# Actuating a horn

Tags: batteries, resistance, wire, automotive

I recently tried to sound a horn (the type normally used in cars) using a 12V battery. The problem is that that, if I **directly connect the horn's terminals to the battery**, it **works perfectly fine**. But when I **connect it using wires**, it **does not work**. The conclusion I've come to is that the wire's resistance s too high (2 ohms). Would that be a plausible reason or is there something else that I'm overlooking?

Comment: That's not really plausible. A typical car horn is connected by wires and a relay. Bad wires maybe? Internal breaks?

Comment: Not unless you're using _really_ thin wires. Do you know the wire gauge?

Comment: What kind of battery are you using?

Comment: 2 Ohms is a lot of resistance for a wire, and will definitely interfere with the operation of an automobile horn. They generally need lots of current to operate, and 2 Ohms of resistance will drastically reduce the available current.

Comment: @rdtsc 6 amps is plenty for most horns. It may be quieter but would still work.

Comment: ...if [6A will get it through](http://www.secondchancegarage.com/public/508.cfm) one-half oscillation. Depends on the [horn and how long the "wire" is](http://bbs.homeshopmachinist.net/threads/37149-how-many-amps-does-a-car-horn-draw?s=462cbedddd1d5100d73fa0c0457e4791&p=477621#post477621). I guess as of 2012, they finally [may be changing somewhat](http://www.foxnews.com/leisure/2012/09/10/automakers-update-car-horn-to-keep-up-with-times/).

Comment: I am suspicious of your report that the resistance of the wire is 2 Ohms. Can you please explain how you came to that conclusion? Maybe post a picture of the wires, if you are able to do so easily. If it is copper wire, then it is most unlikely to have such high resistance even if it is very thin.

Comment: But it is also difficult to accurately measure the resistance of copper wire unless you are somewhat savvy in such matters.

Comment: How do you connect the horn terminals directly to the battery when they're **this** far apart, and the battery terminals are **that** far apart, or do you use wires for that as well, just shorter ones? How long and fat is a piece of wire?

Comment: @mkeith Well, I measured the wire resistance using a multimeter (don't know if that's the correct way) and it showed 2 ohms...

Comment: @Passerby I'm using 12 V lead acid battery rated at 2Ah

Comment: If you just touch the two test leads directly together, what does the multimeter say?

Answer (score 2):

Old car horns are just big buzzers .An electromagnet is supposed to pull in a armature and open its contact cutting its power .when the open contact occurs the magnetic field dies away and the armature falls back to its rest position allowing for the cycle to keep repeating itself.When a horn is running the duty cycle of the current pulses       is generally less than 50% .This means that the peak current is several times the average current.If you place too much resistance in the circuit you will find that the horn wont start but it can draw more than its rated current. I guess it would be possible to burn out a car horn this way.Most cars have a horn relay that is close to the battery .The horn switch can be further away.I havent tried this but i think a solid state switch would work.